# Testing the method with Spring Security authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, testing

I have a method

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public List<User> getInvitations() throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    log.info("Called with outgoing {}", outgoing);

    final String id = ((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getId();

    return this.findUser(id).getSentInvitations()
            .stream()
            .map(ServiceUtils::toUserDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The method receives the ID of the logged in user during operation. Before performing the test, he performs

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    final Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
    grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(SecurityRole.ROLE_USER.toString()));

    Authentication authentication
            = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    new CustomUserDetails(
                            UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                            UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                            grantedAuthorities,
                            "1"
                    ), null);
    SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    sc.setAuthentication(authentication);
}
```

and I'm doing a test

```
/**
 * Test the getInvitations method.
 */
@Test
public void canGetInvitations() {
    final String id = "1";
    final UserEntity entity = Mockito.mock(UserEntity.class);
    Mockito
            .when(this.userRepository.findByUniqueIdAndEnabledTrue(id))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(entity));
    Assert.assertTrue(this.userSearchService.getInvitations().isEmpty());
}
```

However, it turns out that `((CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getId();` returned `null`, even though `id` I gave `1` in `@Before`.

Why can not I correctly set up an authorized user in Spring Security?

Comment: Are you getting a NullPointerException or is `getId()` returning null?

Comment: Yes. I have my own ```UserDetails``` implementation. This is ```CustomUserDetails``` with the new ```id``` field. It turns out that it is null when getting.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Is the security context itself null or only the id is null?